# how can I attach values to struct sembuf that is in a struct converted to a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, semaphore

I need to pass some data to shared memory, that will only accept pointers. So I need the semaphore to be in this structure, but if it is I cant add values to it. how can I fix it?
so, this is the structure:

```
typedef struct querem_usar {
 int conta_homem;
 int conta_mulher;
 int conta_crianca;

 struct sembuf lock[4];
 struct sembuf unlock[4];

} queremUsar;
```

and this is how I have to declare it:

```
queremUsar *banheiro;
```

But if I try to set a value to lock or unlock, like this:

```
banheiro->lock[0].sem_num   = 0; 
banheiro->lock[0].sem_op   = -1;
banheiro->lock[0].sem_flg   = 0;
banheiro->unlock[0].sem_num = 0; 
banheiro->unlock[0].sem_op = 1; 
banheiro->unlock[0].sem_flg = 0;
```

I get segmentation fault. I already tried to use malloc, like this:

```
banheiro->lock = (struct sembuf*)malloc(sizeof(struct sembuf));
banheiro->unlock = (struct sembuf*)malloc(sizeof(struct sembuf));
```

but it gave me the error:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct sembuf[4]’ from type 
‘struct sembuf *’
```

Please, help me fix it? The entire code is here: https://gist.github.com/4553796
the line 71 shouldn't be commented, i did this to test the code. Go ahead and try it, it's for university so it's not complicated at all, it should be the unisex bathroom problem using shared memory (shm, I cant use threads) and semop() as the semaphores.

Answer (score 0):

use this structure defination

```
typedef struct querem_usar {
 int conta_homem;
 int conta_mulher;
 int conta_crianca;

 struct sembuf *lock[4];
 struct sembuf *unlock[4];

 } queremUsar;
```

This will work

Comment: Unfortunately it dint.. now it gives me an error:


    error: request for member ‘sem_num’ in something not a structure or union

and a lot of note and warnings like this one:

    sem.h:59: note: expected ‘struct sembuf *’ but argument is of type ‘struct sembuf **’
    projeto.c:74: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘semop’ from incompatible pointer type

Answer (score 0):

You need to first allocate memory for your banheiro.

In line 25 you declare your pointer "queremUsar *banheiro;". This points to a random area in memory. So any access you do before allocating the necessary memory will cause SEGFAULT if your lucky.

And you do not need to allocate memory for banheiro->lock and banheiro->unlock since you define it to be an array of 'struct sembuf', and not pointer to it.

Comment: Ok.. can you give me the malloc code line? Because I tried this in every possible way (that I know of) and didn't work...

Comment: banheiro = malloc(sizeof(queremUsar));

Unless you are using a c++ compiler, then you need to explicitly cast the return from malloc to (queremUsar *)

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that and this still doesn't work, and banheiro stops beeing a pointer. You can open the entire code if you like and try to get it to work, if you like challenges. The link is on the problem's description. PS: the need of banheiro being a pointer is line 71, it only accepts pointers.

Comment: ah.. I did not read the entire code first.. banheiro is supposed to point to the shared memory you are requesting. Then you do not need to allocate. But then why do you access the region before you have done shmat?. At the point where you are doing banheiro->lock[0] = ..., banheiro is random.

Comment: Oh God... I can't believe that was it.. hahaha such a silly error. I can't thank you enough, Ajith!! I'm still a newbie and I'd never have guessed that, now I'll never do the same mistake again. Thank you so much!